# Error missing the extra metadata for an update/delete entity

Tags: rest, odata, sharepoint-2013, breeze

when saving (updating) opr delete Entities the "missing the extra metadata for an update/delete entity" Error is thrown.

```
Breeze.Angular" version="1.1.1"
Breeze.Angular.Directives" version="1.3.10" 
Breeze.Angular.SharePoint" version="0.10.0" 
Breeze.Client" version="1.5.3"
Breeze.DataService.SharePoint" version="0.10.0" 
Breeze.Metadata.Helper" version="1.0.8"
```

Read the Entites is no problem. When debugging breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js line 297 function updateEntityNode...
metadata is obtained by Sharepoint, etag and type as defined -> type = "SP.Data.LearningPathsListItem" as I went along the pluralsight course and blog from Andre Connell. However on line on line 301 node.$entityType is undefined and __metadata is not copied to extraMetadata. I've no clue why as I went strictly to blog an course when defining the entities. Anyone to point out how to fix $entityType? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've brought this to Andrew Connell's attention. He's tied up at the moment but we'll try and follow up as soon as we can.

You might help us help you by adding some information to your question:

- Describe your SharePoint source. A sanitized URL will probably do.
- Show us the metadata you wrote for the `LearningPathsListItem`
- Show us the JSON returned from SharePoint in response to the successful query (you can scrap this from the pertinent traffic visible in the "Network" tab of the browser's developer tools [F12]).

Comment: OK, now I have started the app again and everything runs just fine. I didn't change anything.